# How to analyze strings from a dynamically allocated char array in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

```
char *arrList;
arrList = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
arrList = input;
printf("%s\n", arrList);  //The words I am attempting to analyze
    
int numWords = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < *arrList; i++){
    if(arrList[i] == ' '){
        numWords++;
    }
}

char *ptr = strtok(arrList, delim);
printf("\n%s",ptr);

int j = 0 ;
while(j <= numWords){
   checkWord(*ptr);  //This is where I am having issues
    
   ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
   printf("\n%s",ptr);
   j++;
}
```

So I am attempting to take in input such as "qwp plm vzxyui coqwerty" and put it in a dynamically allocated array. Furthermore I am suppose to be able to separate some words from others and then decode said words. The issue I am having is being able to take these segments or words and "look" at them one by one to test them.

```
void checkWord(char ptr){ // be able to test to see if word is valid
    char *word;
    word = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    *word = ptr;
    
    printf("\n Word is : %s",word);
}
```

This is the function I am trying to look at each word with. When I run the program I seem to be losing memory somewhere and the information wont pass through.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Im just trying to learn :)

Below is additional code that is before the while loop

```
 char input[300];

/* set up an infinite loop */
while(1){
    /* get line of input from standard input */
    printf ("\nEnter input to check or q to quit\n");
    fgets(input, 300, stdin);

    /* remove the newline character from the input */
    int i = 0;
    while (input[i] != '\n' && input[i] != '\0'){
        i++;
}
input[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: This statement arrList = input; produces a memory leak.

Comment: This statement for(int i = 0; i < *arrList; i++){ does not make a sense.

Comment: The function checkWord is also incorrect and does not make a sense. So the resume is all your code is invalid.:)

Comment: You really need to post more of your code. For example, we need to see the definition of and code that sets `input`.

Comment: @CraigEstey You are wrong. We need not to see more code because the presented code is entirely invalid. The question should be closed.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, as presented, it needs work. But, I think it's reasonable to give OP the chance to improve the question before taking precipitous action.

Comment: @CraigEstey   I will edit it with what you requested, thank you for being compassionate.

Comment: OT: regarding: `arrList = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  Suggest removing that cast.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the standard as 1  multiplying anything by 1 has not effect and this expression just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.  3) `malloc()` can fail.  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` to output to `stderr` your message

Comment: regarding: `fgets(input, 300, stdin);`  Since `input` is (upto) 300 characters, how come `arrList` is only 4 characters?  The most likely result is overflowing the `arrList` buffer, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: regarding; `arrList = input;`    since `input` is (probably) an array.  Note a 'bare' array reference returns the address of the array, not the contents, so this assignment will place the address of `input` into `arrList` Suggest using `strcpy()` or `nemcpy()` to copy the data bytes to the array.

Comment: regarding: `char *ptr = strtok(arrList, delim);`  What is the contents of the string: `delim`?

Comment: OT: regarding: `int i = 0;
    while (input[i] != '\n' && input[i] != '\0'){
        i++;`  This is a poor idea.  Suggest: `input[ strcspn( input, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

There were a number of issues with the code. This was compounded by not having the *full* code.

Generally, when to use `char`, `char *`, and `char **`. The code couldn't compile cleanly.

When *searching* a list, we want to merely scan an existing list (i.e. we don't need allocate something new).

Because of all this, the bugs are too numerous to mention here.

But, I've put together a version that shows original code and [my] refactored code, with annotations for the bugs.

And, a second version that is cleaned up and working

---

Here's the annotated version. It is incomplete and won't compile but just tries to show what some of the bugs were. Note that I had to take considerable "poetic license" to reorder and regroup the code. The old vs. new code is bracketed with `#if BUG` or `#if ! BUG`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

// NOTE/BUG: this a pointer to a _single_ string and _not_ a pointer to a _list_
// of strings -- and, we need to keep track of the count in the list
#if BUG
char *arrList;
#else
size_t arrCount;
char **arrlist;
#endif

// be able to test to see if word is valid
// NOTE/BUG: "char ptr" is a single character and _not_ a pointer to an array
// of characters (i.e. a C string)
#if BUG
void
checkWord(char ptr)
#else
int
checkWord(const char *ptr)
#endif
{
    char *word;

#if ! BUG
    int arridx;
    char **arrcur;
    int match = 0;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: no need to malloc anything new when _checking_ for a list
#if BUG
    word = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    *word = ptr;
    printf("\n Word is : %s", word);
#else
    for (int arridx = 0; arridx < arrCount; ++arridx) {
        word = arrList[arridx];
        if (strcmp(str, word) == 0) {
            match = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("The word '%s' %s a valid word\n",match ? "is" : "is not");

    return match;
#endif
}

#if ! BUG
void
addword(const char *str)
{
    size_t arridx;

    arridx = arrCount++;

    arrList = realloc(arrList,sizeof(*arrlist) * (arrCount + 1));

    if (arrList == NULL) {
        printf("addword: unable to realloc -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    arrList[arridx] = strdup(str);
    arrList[arridx] = NULL;
}

void
loadwords(FILE *fin)
{
    char *cp;
    char *inp;
    char input[300];

    while (1) {
        cp = fgets(input,sizeof(input),fin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        inp = input;
        while (1) {
            cp = strtok(inp," \t\n");
            inp = NULL;

            if (cp == NULL)
                break;

            addword(cp);
        }
    }
}
#endif

#if BUG
void
checkallold(const char *file)
{

    arrList = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    arrList = input;
    //The words I am attempting to analyze
    printf("%s\n", arrList);

    for (int i = 0; i < *arrList; i++) {
        if (arrList[i] == ' ') {
            numWords++;
        }
    }

    char *ptr = strtok(arrList, delim);
    printf("\n%s", ptr);

    int j = 0;
    int numWords = 0;
    while (j <= numWords) {
        // This is where I am having issues
        checkWord(*ptr);

        ptr = strtok(NULL, delim);
        printf("\n%s", ptr);
        j++;
    }
}
#endif

#if ! BUG
void
checkallfix(FILE *fin)
#if BUG
    /* set up an infinite loop */
#else
    // read in all words to check
#endif
    while (1) {
        /* get line of input from standard input */
        printf("\nEnter input to check or q to quit\n");
#if BUG
        fgets(input, 300, stdin);
#else
        if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), fin) == NULL)
            break;
#endif

        /* remove the newline character from the input */
#if BUG
        int i = 0;
        while (input[i] != '\n' && input[i] != '\0') {
            i++;
        }
        input[i] = '\0';
#else
        cp = strchr(input,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;
        checkWord(input);
#endif
    }
}
#endif

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
#if BUG
    char input[300];
#else
    char *cp;
    char *file;
    FILE *fin;
#endif

#if ! BUG
    --argc;
    ++argv;

    // read in list of valid words
    if (argc <= 0) {
        printf("No dictionary file specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    --argc;
    file = *argv++;
    fin = fopen(file,"r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        printf("unable to open list of dictionary words '%s' -- %s\n",
            file,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    loadwords(fin);
    fclose(fin);
#endif

#if BUG
    checkallold();
#else
    // read in list of valid words
    if (argc <= 0) {
        fin = stdin;
        checkallfix(fin);
    }
    else {
        --argc;
        file = *argv++;
        fin = fopen(file,"r");
        if (fin == NULL) {
            printf("unable to open list of words to check '%s' -- %s\n",
                file,strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        checkallfix(fin);
        fclose(fin);
    }
#endif
}
```

---

Here's the cleaned up, refactored, and working version. I've added some more comments to explain what's happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t arrcount;                        // number of elements in arrlist
char **arrlist;                         // dictionary list

// checkWord -- be able to test to see if word is valid
int
checkWord(const char *ptr)
{
    char *word;
    int arridx;
    int match = 0;

    for (arridx = 0;  arridx < arrcount;  ++arridx) {
        word = arrlist[arridx];
        if (strcmp(ptr,word) == 0) {
            match = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (match)
        printf("The word '%s' is in the dictionary\n",ptr);
    else
        printf("'%s' is not a valid word\n",ptr);

    return match;
}

// addword -- add new dictionary word
void
addword(const char *str)
{
    size_t arridx;

    arridx = arrcount++;

    // extend the dictionary list (allowing an extra element for a NULL)
    arrlist = realloc(arrlist,sizeof(*arrlist) * (arrcount + 1));
    if (arrlist == NULL) {
        printf("addword: unable to realloc -- %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    // we must dup the string because, otherwise, it will be lost on the
    // next input line when the 'input' buffer is reused
    arrlist[arridx] = strdup(str);

    // add null pointer at end (e.g. just like argv)
    arrlist[arrcount] = NULL;
}

// loadwords -- load up all dictionary words
void
loadwords(FILE *fin)
{
    char *cp;
    char *inp;
    char input[300];

    while (1) {
        // get a line
        cp = fgets(input,sizeof(input),fin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        // parse all tokens/words in the line
        inp = input;
        while (1) {
            cp = strtok(inp," \t\n");
            inp = NULL;

            // stop if nothing more
            if (cp == NULL)
                break;

            // add single new word
            addword(cp);
        }
    }
}

// checkallfix -- check all words
void
checkallfix(FILE *fin)
{
    char *cp;
    char input[300];

    // read in all words to check
    while (1) {
        // prompt user
        if (fileno(fin) == 0)
            printf("\nEnter input to check or q to quit\n");

        // get input line
        cp = fgets(input,sizeof(input),fin);
        if (cp == NULL)
            break;

        /* remove the newline character from the input */
        cp = strchr(input,'\n');
        if (cp != NULL)
            *cp = 0;

        // stop ...
        if (strcmp(input,"q") == 0)
            break;

        // is this word in the dictionary?
        checkWord(input);
    }
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *file;
    FILE *fin;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    // read in list of valid words
    if (argc <= 0) {
        printf("No dictionary file specified\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    --argc;
    file = *argv++;
    fin = fopen(file,"r");
    if (fin == NULL) {
        printf("unable to open list of dictionary words '%s' -- %s\n",
            file,strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
    loadwords(fin);
    fclose(fin);

    // check words against dictionary
    if (argc <= 0) {
        fin = stdin;
        checkallfix(fin);
    }
    else {
        --argc;
        file = *argv++;
        fin = fopen(file,"r");
        if (fin == NULL) {
            printf("unable to open list of words to check '%s' -- %s\n",
                file,strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        }
        checkallfix(fin);
        fclose(fin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a sample dictionary file:

```
qwp plm vzxyui coqwerty
able baker charlie delta
quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
sherlock holmes was a fine detective
```

---

Here's a sample input file to test against the dictionary:

```
coqwerty
able
baker
charlie
delta
epsilon
fox
the
shylock
homes
bill and ted
bogus
journey
```

---

Here is the output of the program:

```
The word 'coqwerty' is in the dictionary
The word 'able' is in the dictionary
The word 'baker' is in the dictionary
The word 'charlie' is in the dictionary
The word 'delta' is in the dictionary
'epsilon' is not a valid word
The word 'fox' is in the dictionary
The word 'the' is in the dictionary
'shylock' is not a valid word
'homes' is not a valid word
'bill and ted' is not a valid word
'bogus' is not a valid word
'journey' is not a valid word
```